# php сессия после закрытия браузера

Tags: php

при авторизацци на сайт использую сессии

```
$_SESSION['session_username']=$username;
```

но живет эта сессия до тех пор пока не закрывается браузер ! 
как реализовать авторизацию например как vk.com  чтобы после закрытия браузера сессия не закрывалась и в принципе оставалась активной до тех пор пока пользователь не нажмет "logout"

Comment: использоваться cookie?
http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать [куки](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php). Я [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503913/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php/503921#503921) когда-то отвечал про сессии.

В куках Вы можете задать время жизни, при создании переменной, и браузер будет хранить данные всё это время, или пока Вы не удалите их. Но, Вы должны защищать такие данные, и ни в коем случае не передавать в куки данные для авторизации или личные/секретные данные, т.к. эти данные передаются на клиент, и могут быть прочитаны.

Если Вы установите время жизни кук в 0, то они будут сессионными, т.е. сотрутся после закрытия браузера. Как тот же `SESSID`, который затирается, и после открытия страницы снова, не отправляется на сервер, поэтому PHP не может отпределить старую сессию, и создает новую.

Comment: Сессия в PHP и так основана на куках. А смотреть нужно сюда http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params

Comment: If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session. Видимо Вы не перешли по ссылке, там про это и рассказывается.

Comment: Только у вас про куки вообще, а тут про конкретные куки которые лежат в основе механизма PHP-сессий. А как они работают я прекрасно знаю